# Getting Console.ReadLine() functionality in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm in the process of writing a basic text game using `WinForms`; this started off as a `Console` app.

In my `Player` class, I have this method, which currently reads a `name` and `characterClass` from `Console.ReadLine()` and builds the `Player` object from these parameters:

```
public static Player CreateCharacter()
{
    string name;
    string characterClass;

    //InputOutput.Write("Please enter your character's name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    characterClass = Console.ReadLine(); //SelectClass();

    switch (characterClass.ToLower())
    {
        case "warrior":
            return new Player(name, new Warrior());
        case "archer":
            return new Player(name, new Archer());
        case "mage":
            return new Player(name, new Mage());
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

This method worked well with the `Console` project, but now that I'm moving over to `WinForms` I'm unsure how to get similar functionality from a `TextBox`.

I am trying to build a method similar to the following:

```
public void StartNewGame()
{
    AddTextToOutputBox("To begin, please enter a name for your character: ");
    GetInputFromTextbox(input1); //wait for input from textbox
    AddTextToOutputBox("Now, enter a class. [Warrior], [Archer], or [Mage]:");
    GetInputFromTextbox(input2); //wait for input from textbox

    Player.CreateCharacter(input1, input2); //create the player
}
```

Where I output a message to `OutputBox`, wait for input from `InputBox`, and create a `Player` from these parameters.

I'm unsure how to proceed here, but I would like the functionality to be similar to that of `Console.ReadLine()` because (as it stands now), the method I'm trying to call depends on input from the user.

- *What options are available to mimic the functionality of* `Console.ReadLine()` *with a* `TextBox` *in WinForms?* *Is there a different control better suited to this task?*
- *Is this method the "right" way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, or would I be better off with a different method altogether?*

Comment: You put your input fields on a form (name, class, etc) and then you have a submit or next or done, or what have you button. The user fills in the text boxes and presses the button. You process the event that the button generates on click in your code.

Comment: Why don´t you monitor the TEXTBOX events (like TextChanged) to ensure that have a valid text there before exit to the next question to user? You may also utilize a Friend/Public variable to check this between different textboxes events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Win Forms` user interaction paradigm is slightly different from `Console` apps.
You can fill many fields and then submit a form with all the values at once.

In your case I would use `TextBox` control for the character name and a `ComboBox` or a `RaioButton` control for the character class.

Then, when user clicks the submit button, 
`Player.CreateCharacter(input1, input2); //create the player` is called.

In addition, you can use validation controls to verify user input.

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing. Thanks!